# Update primefaces parent component, without re-render its datatable child

Tags: jsf, datatable, primefaces, lazy-loading

I want to update the **parent component** (an outputpanel) of a datatable **without** the datatable itself (**lazy loaded**) so that its`@load` method will not get triggered (it performs a very heavy API request so I do not want it to be called for no reason).

So far I have tried to use the `:not()` operator from the update event but when I do so, the parent component does not update itself too, why that strange behaviour? Code example below:

**Parent component I want to be updated apart from its datatable child**

```
<h:form id="myForm">
  
    <p:outputPanel id="parentContainer" styleClass="fullHeight parent"
               style="display:#{(myBean.showCreateForm == false)?'block;':'none'}">

      <p:dataTable id="myDatatable" lazy="true"
                 styleClass="exclude" ...
      </p:dataTable>

    </p:outputPanel>

</h:form>
```

**Button updating the upper form**

```
// this button toggles the myBean.showCreateForm variable show it toggles the upper div
<p:commandButton update="@(.parent :not(.exclude))" partialSubmit="true" ajax="true">
```

The behaviour I would like to have from the code above is:

1)On click of the button I want to `toggle` the `parentContainer` div but 2)do not re-render its datatable through the ajax update and call its `@load` method (since it is lazy loaded).

Unfortunately **when I exclude the datatable through the `:not` selector, the parent element (`parentContainer`) does not also update/toggles.**

Is there any way to achieve my case?

Comment: I don't think you can update a parent and ignore the child as JSF by definiton when it renders the parent will re-render all its children.

Comment: Hi Melloware, thanks for the respons! Yes that seems legit but is there any way I could  recognize that case where the datatable is updated so in the @load method I could skip the API request?

Comment: You might be able to but not anyway that I am aware of.  Doesn't mean its not possible just not in my knowledge base.

Comment: I managed to achieve my scenario by adding/removing under the corresponding circumstances a variable in the `facescontext externalcontext requestMap` to recognize when i want to fetch data from the api and when not, which is obviously not an optimal way but it works good for the moment, thanks for your time!